# Why is marshalling / unmarshalling JSON through Avro so slow?

Tags: json, scala, avro

I am very new to Avro, working with 1.7.7.

I have a schema that is compiled.

I am trying to marshall through JSON, figured I would take advantage of the validation and such that Avro provides.

However, the Avro marshalling is wicked slow (at least the way I am doing it).

The following is 10,000 iterations through my object.  The object has a nested object, and a nested array of objects on it, so it is complex.  While it is complex, there aren't a lot of data elements.  In the array, I have 3 items, so not a ton there.

The following are the results of my performance test:

```
CONVERTING TO JSON (THROUGH AVRO) AVG: 74 MICROS
CONVERTING FROM JSON (THROUGH AVRO) AVG: 433 MICROS
CONVERTING TO JSON (JACKSON STREAMING) AVG: 16 MICROS
CONVERTING FROM JSON (JACKSON STREAMING) AVG: 9 MICROS
```

The last two (JACKSON STREAMING) I am using pure Jackson streaming API as opposed to AVRO.  The performance boost is ridiculous.

I am feeling like I am doing something wrong here.  The following is the code snippet that handles the JSON <--> AVRO stuff:

```
 val spanDatumReader = new SpecificDatumReader[Span](Span.getClassSchema)
 val spanDatumWriter = new SpecificDatumWriter[Span](Span.getClassSchema)

 def fromJson(spanJson:String):Span = {

  val spanJsonDecoder = DecoderFactory.get.jsonDecoder(Span.getClassSchema, spanJson)
  spanDatumReader.read(null, spanJsonDecoder)
 }

 def toJson(span:Span):String = {

    val writer = new StringWriter()
    val jsonGenerator = jsonFactory.createJsonGenerator(writer)
    val spanJsonEncoder = EncoderFactory.get.jsonEncoder(Span.getClassSchema, jsonGenerator)
    spanDatumWriter.write(span, spanJsonEncoder)
    spanJsonEncoder.flush()
    jsonGenerator.close()
    writer.toString
 }
```

I am hoping someone can point me to what I am doing wrong.  I would think that with a compiled Schema, that the marshalling / unmarshalling should be *close* to doing it by hand, but so far that is not the case :(

Just an update, I ran it 100,000 times with the following results.  Closer (maybe JVM starting up or something else warming up), but there is still a big difference:

```
CONVERTING TO JSON (THROUGH AVRO) AVG: 16 MICROS
CONVERTING FROM JSON (THROUGH AVRO) AVG: 21 MICROS
CONVERTING TO JSON (JACKSON STREAMING) AVG: 3 MICROS
CONVERTING FROM JSON (JACKSON STREAMING) AVG: 2 MICROS
```

Thanks!

Comment: The official Avro library is slow. Here's the explanation regarding a faster approach for java https://techblog.rtbhouse.com/2017/04/18/fast-avro/. Here's for python - https://github.com/pluralsight/spavro.